# DataTable how to get data from AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I've been making CRUD tables in school traditionally through scaffolding per page and wanted to try out if I could do all operations without using Partial View. I opted to use AJAX which I followed a guide here: https://dzone.com/articles/crud-operation-in-aspnet-mvc-using-ajax-and-bootst

Everthing works flawlessly, but I wanted to use DataTable API to add Search and sorting functionality to the table. This is what the table looks like 
[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKJfd.png).

As you can see it doesn't recognize the data coming from the JS that I made, most notably with "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries". Is there any way to load data from AJAX to the DataTable script? Thanks very much! I'll provide my code below.

EDIT: I put the DataTable initilization in Inventory.js and the DataTable SOMETIMES works on page load. It's very random when trying to refresh the page multiple times. I tried putting a delay before the page loads to see if that makes any difference but it doesn't work. Anybody know what's going?

Inventory(model)

```
    public List<Inventory> ListAll()
    {
        List<Inventory> lst = new List<Inventory>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetCon()))
        {
            con.Open();
            string query = @"SELECT * FROM Inventory";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                            lst.Add(new Inventory
                        {   
                            InventoryId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["inv_id"]),
                            Category = Helper.Decrypt(dr["category_name"].ToString()),
                            Name = Helper.Decrypt(dr["item_name"].ToString()),
                            Details = Helper.Decrypt(dr["item_details"].ToString()),
                            Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(dr["quantity"]),
                            CsbCode = Helper.Decrypt(dr["csb_code"].ToString()),
                            Notes = Helper.Decrypt(dr["notes"].ToString()),
                            Location = Helper.Decrypt(dr["location"].ToString()),
                            DateCreated = DateTime.Parse(dr["date_created"].ToString()),
                            LastModified = DateTime.Parse(dr["last_modified"].ToString()),
                        });
                    }
                    return lst;
                }                 
            }

        }
    }
```

InventoryController.cs

```
 public JsonResult List()
    {
        return Json(invDB.ListAll(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Inventory.js(How I get my data)

```
function loadData() {
$.ajax({
    url: "/Inventory/List",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        var html = '';
        $.each(result, function (key, item) {
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td>' + item.InventoryId + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + item.Category + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + item.Name + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + item.Details + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + item.Quantity + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + item.CsbCode + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + item.Notes + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + item.Location + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + dateTimeFormat(item.DateCreated) + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + dateTimeFormat(item.LastModified) + '</td>';
            html += '<td><a href="#" onclick="return getbyID(' + item.InventoryId + ')">Edit</a> | <a href="#" onclick="Delele(' + item.InventoryId + ')">Delete</a></td>';
            html += '</tr>';
        });
        $('.tbody').html(html);
    },
    error: function (errormessage) {
        alert(errormessage.responseText);
    }
});
```

}

Index (DataTable script):

```
    @section scripts {
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.uikit.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#user').DataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'print'
                ]

            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: I guess that your Create Date and Last Modified date are in non-standard date format. Mind sharing the output to see how it is actually formatted? https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/45692/how-to-date-sort-as-date-instead-of-string

Comment: hi ghitesh! i think you misread the title, but the data is being displayed on the table but DataTable isn't recognizing the data as shown in the image I linked [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKJfd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am using 1.10 Jquery Datatables and for the templating i am using Underscore JS.

Here is my code for loading from server side.

Put this template and table in your html code.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" id="tblAccounts"></table>

<script type="text/template" id="tmpl_Grid">
    <td><%= Id %></td>
    <td><%= Amount %></td>
    <td><%= Date %></td>
    <td><%= Type %></td>        
</script>
```

Then this method for js to load data from server side.

```
function  Load() {
            var tmpl = _.template($('#tmpl_Grid').html());
            $('#tblAccounts').DataTable({
                "dom": "<'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>",
                "paging": true,
                "info": true,
                "ordering": true,
                "search": true,
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "destroy": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Accounts/LoadList",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "data": function (d) {
                        d.startDate = $("#txtStartDate").val();
                        d.endDate = $("#txtEndDate").val();
                    }
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": null, "title": "ID", "className": "", "orderable": false, "searchable": false },
                    { "data": null, "title": "AMOUNT", "className": "", "orderable": false, "searchable": false },
                    { "data": null, "title": "DATE", "className": "", "orderable": false, "searchable": false },
                    { "data": null, "title": "TYPE", "className": "", "orderable": false, "searchable": false }
                ],
                "order": [[0, "asc"]],
                "rowCallback": function (row, data) {
                    $(row).html(tmpl(data));
                },
                "initComplete": function (settings, json) {

                }
            });
        }
```

Here is the code for controller. I am using EntityFrameword for database processing you can use your own method or technique.

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> LoadList(string startDate, string endDate)
        {
           var search = Request.Form["search[value]"] + "";

            var totalCount = 0;
            var fList = _context.Expenses.Include(x => x.AccountType).AsQueryable();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                fList = fList.Where(x => x.Description.ToLower().Trim().Contains(search.ToLower().Trim()));
            }

            var list = await fList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Skip(start).Take(length).Select(x => new
            {
                x.Id,
                x.Amount,
                Date = x.Date != null ? x.Date.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") : "",
                Type = x.AccountTypeId != null ? x.AccountType.Name : "",
                x.Description,
                x.BillAmount,
                x.Payment,
                x.AccountTypeId
            }).ToListAsync();

            if (list.Any())
            {
                totalCount = fList.Count();
            }

            var result = JObject.FromObject(new
            {
                draw,
                recordsFiltered = totalCount,
                recordsTotal = totalCount,
                data = list
            });
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: I may assume, OP is developing his own app, not yours. So, I'm guessing irrelevant lump of code that has almost nothing in common with context, described in original post (starting from `serverSide: true`, bunch of your own classes and AJAX method 'POST' as opposed to 'GET' in OP's code), is useless. Don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help. I got it to work consistently with a post I found on the same forum.

I changed my code for getting my data to this. Apparently you need to append the data, this was the most important thing that got my DataTables to work.

$("#user tbody").append(html);

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/Artwork/List",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {

        $.each(result, function (key, item) {
            var html = '';
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td>' + item.ArtID + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + item.Name + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + item.Details + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + item.Location + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + item.Notes + '</td>';          
            html += '<td>' + dateTimeFormat(item.DateCreated) + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + dateTimeFormat(item.LastModified) + '</td>';
            html += '<td><a href="#" onclick="return getbyID(' + item.ArtID + ')">Edit</a> | <a href="#" onclick="Delele(' + item.ArtID + ')">Delete</a></td>';
            html += '</tr>';
            $("#user tbody").append(html);
        });
        $('#user').DataTable({
            destroy: true,              
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible' ,
                    }
                },
                'colvis'
            ],
            columnDefs: [{
                visible: false
            }]               
        });
```

Again, thank you!

Comment: You shall **NOT** use that approach in your production app, despite of solving your problem with async AJAX-response and DataTables initialization (which I've mentioned in my post before), you kept doing several things wrong or suboptimally: the major issue is that you unnecessarily destroy and create DataTable upon each AJAX-call which is a waste of performance, instead, you're supposed to use `ajax` option (as being suggested in my post), this would eliminate another (minor) side effect - now, you're not able to access AJAX response data via DataTables API.

Comment: Another lowlight is that you do all the HTML heavy lifting on your own, which simply doesn't make sense (to load the library and overload your own script with extra lines of code to re-invent the feature being already in place). By the way, your approach to do that could've been real headache with bigger number of columns.